# Por que eu não consigo acessar o vetor de inteiros na função main()?

Tags: c, ponteiro

Não consigo acessar as posições do vetor de inteiros que carreguei na função carrega. Naquela função eu consigo de forma correta acessar os dados com:

```
printf("%d\n", n[i]);
```

Mas na função `main()`, abaixo de onde chamo a função carrega, quando tento acessar qualquer posição desse vetor de inteiros o programa simplesmente fecha. Acredito que estou trabalhando errado com ponteiros

```
#include <stdio.h>

void carrega (int *n);

int main
(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    int *n=NULL;
    carrega (n);
    printf("%d\n", n[0]); //Erro aqui, não consegue acessar.
}

void carrega (int *n)
{
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f = NULL;
    f = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r");

    n = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0;i<3;i++){
    fscanf (f, "%d", &n[i]);
    printf("%d\n", n[i]);  //Tudo ok
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O problema é meio subtil devido a estar a trabalhar com vetores e ponteiros, mas é algo simples.

Imagine este cenário:

```
void altera(int x){
    x = 10;
}
```

Chamando assim:

```
int var1 = 50;
altera(var1);
printf("%d", var1); //50
```

[Veja no ideone](https://ideone.com/fokdql)

Acontece que no C os parametros são sempre passados por copia, logo alterar o valor de um parametro numa função não altera a variavel original. Olhando para este exemplo que dei, o parametro `x` é uma copia do valor que `var1` tinha, logo alterar `x` na função não altera o valor de `var1`.

Você fez exatamente o mesmo mas através de um ponteiro, ora veja:

```
void carrega (int *n){
    ...
    n = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));
    ...
}

int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    int *n=NULL;
    carrega (n);
    printf("%d\n", n[0]);
}
```

Veja como é exatamente igual ao exemplo que dei mas agora com um `int*`, um ponteiro de inteiro. Você cria um ponteiro, passa-o à função na esperança que a função o altere, mas lembre-se que o que é passado é uma copia do ponteiro. Logo fazer `n = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));` não altera o `n` que tem no `main` mas sim a copia desse `n` que tem na função.

Aqui tem duas soluções para resolver

1) Retornar o valor com que queria alterar:

```
int* carrega (int *n);
//^-- agora retorno de int*

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int *n = NULL;
    n = carrega (n); //coloca o valor devolvido de novo em n
    printf("%d\n", n[0]);
}

int* carrega (int *n) {
//^--- agora retorno de int*
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r");
    n = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        fscanf (f, "%d", &n[i]);
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }
    return n; //retorna o novo array alocado
}
```

2) Passar o endereço da variável que quer alterar:

```
void carrega (int **endereco_n);
//                 ^-- agora recebe o endereço do array

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int *n = NULL;
    carrega (&n); //passa o endereço do array através do &
    printf("%d\n", n[0]);
}

void carrega (int **endereco_n) {
//                 ^-- agora recebe o endereço do array
    int i = 0;
    FILE *f = fopen ("arquivo.txt", "r");
    int *n = (int *) malloc(3*sizeof(int));

    for(i=0; i<3; i++) {
        fscanf (f, "%d", &n[i]);
        printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    }
    *endereco_n = n; //altera o array do main através do endereço recebido 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

O código tem alguns problemas e pode ser escrito de forma mais simples, mas o principal é quanto a alocação de memória. Prefira alocar a memória para receber os dados na função onde vai usar. E aí fica mais fácil lembrar de librar com `free()`. Se quiser um código mais robusto tem que fazer uma série de verificar ou ler de uma forma diferente. Este código é bom como exercício básico para ler algo que você tem certeza que tudo dará certo.

Provavelmente há problema em como o dado está no arquivo. Tem certeza que tem uma forma de separa os números? Eles estão válidos? Eu testei com um arquivo muito simples com os dados separados por espaço.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void carrega(int *n) {
    FILE *f = fopen("arquivo.txt", "r");
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) fscanf(f, "%d", &n[i]);
    fclose(f);
}

int main() {
    int *n = malloc(3 * sizeof(int));
    carrega(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) printf("%d\n", n[i]);
    free(n);
    system("pause");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/IO/BufferParameter.c).

Comment: Opa Maniero. Desculpe pelo código meio esquisito. Cortei várias coisas para ficar mais simples de vocês entenderem qual era minha dúvida, não validei o malloc, não utilizei o free, etc ... Na verdade eu precisa realizar toda a alocação dentro da função "carrega" e depois brincar com ela na main. O Isac aqui embaixo me lembrou que eu estava passando a cópia do ponteiro e não o ponteiro em si.

Comment: @EduardoOliveira só que não é assim que as pessoas costumam fazer me C e é um código propenso a erros. De forma geral todas as bibliotecas trabalham com essa ideia de alocar e passar o ponteiro, a sua foge do padrão. É um direito seu fazer assim, mas está fazendo de forma considerada ruim.

Comment: Entendi,  vou seguir sua dica. Esse código que estou fazendo é um exercício bem específico para aprendizado, onde tenho um arquivo que o 1º elemento inteiro informa a quantidade de nºs inteiros que o arquivo possui. Por exemplo:
3 90 100 87  <<< Informa que tenho três inteiros(90,100,87)
Após descobrir a quantidade, precisava colocar esses três em um array, achar o menor valor e printar a ordem inversa desses elementos. Aí o professor pediu para deixar nada na main, inclusive a abertura do arquivo. Como tenho que pegar a quantidade de elementos tive que colocar a abertura na função carrega.